# Iterate Hash constants in Ruby

Tags: ruby, hashmap, constants

I have the following Ruby module:

```
module Test
  Constant1 = {
    :key1 => :value1,
    :key2 => :value2    
  }

  Constant2 = {
    :key1 => :value1,
    :key2 => :value2    
  }
end
```

And I am trying to iterate through the declared Hash constants to print all the keys defined with the following code:

```
Test.constants.each do |constant|
  constant.keys.each do |key|
    puts "key: #{key}"
  end
end
```

But I get a `NoMethodError: undefined method 'keys' for "Constant2":String` and I don't know how to convert that `String` into a real costant. Anyone knows how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works:

```
Test.constants.each do |constant|
  Test.const_get(constant).keys.each do |key|
    puts "key: #{key}"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
Test.constants.each do |c|
  Test.const_get(c).each do |key, value|
    puts "key: #{key}, value: #{value}"
  end
end
```

Comment: Either `.keys.each` or `.each do |key, value|`. :-)

Comment: Good answer too, sorry I could only choose one... +1

Answer (score 0):

The constants you fetch from module Test are actually ["Constant1","Constant2"].
You could store hashes in module variables if you really want to use that in this way.

Comment: Well, the truth is I am not really planning to use it that way :)